# How can I change source of Image in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to make an app with Kivy where when you click the button to go to the second screen, it takes a photo, then uses that photo to use in the second screen as a Kivy Image. I try to reference the image object in my code using Object Property, but when I try to change the source, it returns

'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'source'

My Python Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import random

import time
import cv2
import os

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

Window.size= (500,800)
class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def capture(self):
        try:
            os.remove('faces.jpg')
        except:
            pass
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        image = cv2.imread("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        os.remove("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.3,
            minNeighbors=3,
            minSize=(30, 30)
        )

        print("[INFO] Found {0} Faces!".format(len(faces)))

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            #cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            roi_color = image[y-40:y + h+50, x-20:x + w+40]
            print("[INFO] Object found. Saving locally.")
            cv2.imwrite('faces.jpg', roi_color)

        self.manager.current = 'screen2'


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    imageview = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenTwo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        curdir = os.listdir('.')
        self.imageview.source = 'faces.jpg'




class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)



class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

and my .kv file:

```
<ScreenOne>:

   BoxLayout:
       orientation: 'vertical'
       size: root.size
       Camera:
           pos_hint:{'top': 1,'center_y': 0.5}
           id: camera
           resolution: (640, 480)
           play: True

       Button:
           text: 'Capture'
           size_hint_y: None
           on_press: root.capture()
           background_normal: 'Up.png'
           background_down: 'down.png'

<ScreenTwo>:
   bl:bl
   but:but
   BoxLayout:
       id: bl
       orientation: 'vertical'
       Image:
           id: imageview
           source: 'faces.jpg'
           size: self.texture_size

       Button:
           id:but
           text: 'screen3'
           on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"




<Manager>
   id: screen_manager

   screen_one: screen_one
   screen_two: screen_two




   ScreenOne:
       id: screen_one
       name: "screen1"
       manager: screen_manager

   ScreenTwo:
       id: screen_two
       name: "screen2"
       manager: screen_manager
```

Any Help Would be appreciated!

Comment: You probably need a blank `faces.jpg` as a stand-in, so your app will load.  Don't use `os.remove('faces.jpg')`  just overwrite it.

Comment: The problem with that is that I tried it, but when it goes to the second screen, it uses the original faces.jpg, and not the new overwritten one. The main question that I have is that, Is there a way to reference the image object from the python code?

Comment: I don't remember the specifics, it's been years since I've used kivy.  I know you can `ask_update` https://kivy.org/doc/stable/search.html?check_keywords=yes&area=default&q=ask_update or `reload` https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.image.html?highlight=source#kivy.uix.image.Image.source#reload but I don't recall how those relate to screens / widgets.  You might need to wait 'till *after taking pic* to add that screen to your window manager.  Or remove widget from manager, than add it back in -- if you're taking more than one pic.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<ScreenTwo>` rule add a line to define the value of `imageview`, like this:

```
<ScreenTwo>:
   imageview: imageview
   bl:bl
   but:but
   BoxLayout:
       id: bl
       orientation: 'vertical'
       Image:
           id: imageview
           source: 'faces.jpg'
           size: self.texture_size

       Button:
           id:but
           text: 'screen3'
           on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"
```